# after updating react-native can't run ios

Tags: android, ios, react-native

react native can't run ios&android when update 60.04. I solved android but still i can't run on ios. 
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.59.9&to=0.60.4

Podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'NurSedaGuler' do
  # Pods for RNPushApp
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging' #buraya ekledik
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'



  target 'NurSedaGulerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
  use_native_modules!

end
target 'NurSedaGuler-tvOS' do
  # Pods for RnDiffApp-tvOS
  target 'NurSedaGuler-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>NurSedaGuler</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

react-native.config.js

```
const ios = require('@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios');
const android = require('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android');

module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {}, // grouped into "project"
    },
    platforms: {
        ios: {
          linkConfig: ios.linkConfig,
          projectConfig: ios.projectConfig,
          dependencyConfig: ios.dependencyConfig,
        },
        android: {
          linkConfig: android.linkConfig,
          projectConfig: android.projectConfig,
          dependencyConfig: android.dependencyConfig,
        },
      },
      dependencies: {
        'react-native-exit-app': {
          root: './node_modules/react-native-exit-app',
        },
        "react-native-gesture-handler": {
            platforms: {
              android: null,
              ios: null
            }
          },
      },

};
```

react-native run-ios

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
        ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/syckrr/Documents/ReactNativeProjects/NurSedaGuler/ios/build/NurSedaGuler/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NurSedaGuler.app/Info.plist /Users/syckrr/Documents/ReactNativeProjects/NurSedaGuler/ios/NurSedaGuler/Info.plist
(1 failure)

Comment: Solved. i changed info.plist </array> to <array></array> and now working.